# container_of (inode->i_cdev, struct scull_dev, cdev) explanation

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I was reading on the explanation of `container_of` macro and I got most of it except one thing. How does `inode->I_cdev` point to `cdev`? 
To be sure the `cdev` here is the character device we initialized in our `cdev_init` call .

Comment: `cdev_add(cdev, dev, count)` adds character device to the system, associating device number `dev` with given `cdev` object. When inode is created for given device number, it stores associated `cdev` object in `i_cdev` field.

Answer (score 1):

one more thing to add

dev in "struct cdev" is DD point of view and dev_t in "struct inode" is Fs( file system)  point of view.

also the Struct inode ( part of fs.h)  ---> struct cdev(part of cdev.h & Member object of struct Inode ) ---> ( major , minor )

&  the Struct Dev ( user defined ) ---> struct cdev---> ( major , minor)

both reaches the same point .

Answer (score 1):

if you look in chrdev_open function under fs/char_dev.c file you will see that before opening any character device, its respective i_cdev structure is populated in inode's structure.

```
 p = inode->i_cdev;
 if (!p) {
     struct kobject *kobj;
     int idx;
     spin_unlock(&cdev_lock);
     kobj = kobj_lookup(cdev_map, inode->i_rdev, &idx);
     if (!kobj)
         return -ENXIO;
     new = container_of(kobj, struct cdev, kobj);
     spin_lock(&cdev_lock);
     /* Check i_cdev again in case somebody beat us to it while
        we dropped the lock. */
     p = inode->i_cdev;
     if (!p) {
         inode->i_cdev = p = new;
         list_add(&inode->i_devices, &p->list);
         new = NULL;
     } else if (!cdev_get(p))
         ret = -ENXIO;
 } else if (!cdev_get(p))
     ret = -ENXIO;
```

Well for the inode itself, it must be created when a device node is created.
I dont know much about kobjects, but its some how getting the cdev using kobj, and where we associated that kobject with this perticular device? the answer lies in cdev_add

```
 int cdev_add(struct cdev *p, dev_t dev, unsigned count)
 {
     int error;

     p->dev = dev;
     p->count = count;

     error = kobj_map(cdev_map, dev, count, NULL,
              exact_match, exact_lock, p);
     if (error)
         return error;

     kobject_get(p->kobj.parent);

     return 0;
 }
```